# Filters.geoIntersects returns nothing from Java App while query from Robo 3T returns some

Tags: java, mongodb, geospatial

I have a Java app using MongoDb ( client version 3.12).
The Filters.geoIntersects returns nothing from Java App 
while querying for the same data from Robo 3T returns some and here is code for both Java and script.
What's wrong with my Java code. Am I missing something?
Any help is appreciated.

thanks,

Austin

```js
// Using script in Robo 3T ==> returns a few records
db.getCollection('locations').find( {
     place: {
       $geoIntersects: {
          $geometry: {
             type: "Point" ,
             coordinates: 
                [131.005440819316, 33.7843715591825 ]             
          }
       }
     }
   }
)

// Java code returns nothing 
  collection = db.getCollection("locations");
  Point curPos = new Point(new Position(131.005440819316, 33.7843715591825));
  collection.find(Filters.geoIntersects("place.coordinates", curPos))
            .forEach(new Consumer<Document>() {
                  @Override
                  public void accept(Document t) {
                     logger.info( t.toJson());
                  }
             });
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB driver expects the document must have a field called "coordinates".
So the fix is to remove the coordinates field from the query.

```js
  collection = db.getCollection("locations");
  Point curPos = new Point(new Position(131.005440819316, 33.7843715591825));
  collection.find(Filters.geoIntersects("place", curPos))
            .forEach(new Consumer<Document>() {
                  @Override
                  public void accept(Document t) {
                     logger.info( t.toJson());
                  }
             });
``
```